# Create a segment using a custom event in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I want to create a segment of users which counts something like *total [upgrade] events  > 50*. The upgrade event is a custom category in this case. How can I pass this event through to be used in segmentation?

I have tried using *Event Category matches [upgrade]*, but that only counts players who have done one or more event in this category. I want to segment based on the number of times a user completes an event in this category.

Thanks for any insight you can lend. We're stumped over here!

Comment: I think for future reports it would be easiest if you send a distinct custom metric along with every event you want to use in segments. I'm not sure this can be done in the default configuration.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/